# gridview row delete with jquery dialog

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-ui, webforms

Everything is working fine except that postback does not occur when I delete the row. I put a debugger break inside the OnRowDeleting and OnRowDataBound
The only difference is that you don't have Ajax update panel and script Manger. Below is the image of the Gridview. Nothing happens When I click the ok button.

Below is my code on fresh page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm3.aspx.cs" Inherits="SidePanelGridViewTest.WebForm3" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:IdDatabase %>" 
                    SelectCommand="SELECT TOP 5 ProductID, ProductName FROM [TableA]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="scMan" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPnl" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
            <ContentTemplate>

<asp:GridView ID="grdShoppingCart" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="ProductID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnRowDeleting="OnRowDeleting"  OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductID" HeaderText="ProductID" 
            InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="ProductName"
             />
         <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" ItemStyle-Width="150px" ControlStyle-CssClass="ss-row" >
                        <ItemTemplate>
                              <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnDelete" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/delete1.png" ToolTip="Click To Delete" AlternateText="Click To delete" OnClientClick="myclick(this.id);return false;"/>
                              <asp:Button ID="MyDelete" runat="server" Text="del" CommandName="MyDelete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ProductID") %>' style="display:none"/>

                       </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
 </ContentTemplate>
     </asp:UpdatePanel>
           
        </div>
        <div id ="mydialog" style="display:none" runat="server">
              <h2>Do you really want to delete?</h2>
        </div>
        <script>
    function myclick(mycontrolid) {
        var mydiv = $('#mydialog');

        mydiv.dialog({
            autoOpen: false, modal: true, title: 'Delete?', width: '25%',
            position: { my: 'top', at: 'top+150' },
            buttons: {
                'ok': function () {
                    vbtns = '#' + mycontrolid.replace('imgbtnDelete', 'MyDelete');
                    $(vbtns).click();
                },
                'cancel': function () {
                    mydiv.dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });
        mydiv.dialog('open');
    }

</script>



    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

below is the image of the gridview:

[image]

when I click on "Ok" button in the delete pop up. postback does not occur. I have a debugger break on both OnRowDeleting and OnRowDataBound. when I start running the code, debugger breaks on OnRowDataBound, but clicking on "OK' button on the pop up does not cause postback.

below is the code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace SidePanelGridViewTest
{
    public partial class WebForm3 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        protected void OnRowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
        {
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.RowIndex);


        }

        protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            string x = "Test";

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I’m going to bite.

And the REASON is that I went through this, and the working examples are HORRID – BEYOND suffering!!

So, let’s work through this.

First up, unlike JavaScript (js) “alert” or “confirm”?

Most web stuff and including jQuery.UI does NOT halt, nor does it block code.

This means our “image” button “on click” can’t be used to return true or false, since our dialog does NOT wait. We thus have to get the results of the dialog AND THEN run that delete button code.

Given above?

Then most simple is placing a hidden delete button into that grid. We then have our jQuery.UI “click” that delete button for us.

jQuery.ui expects to “operate” on a jQuery selector. That means $(“please select this thing”)

Often that is some control or button, but for dialogs, most often that is a div you place on the page (and hide it --- FYI: note how we hid the jQuery.UI dialog "div" and ALSO how we hide the delete button with style="display:none").

So, let’s add our delete button – right below the image button (and by the way, you can use an asp.net button here – you’re not limited to an image button).

So, ONLY job of image button is to NOW call our jquery dialog – but it CAN NOT run our server side delete code.

So, let’s add that delete button.

We MOVE the delete stuff to this button FROM the image button.

So, we have this now:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnDelete" runat="server"
           ImageUrl="~/Images/delete1.png" ToolTip="Click To Delete"
           AlternateText="Click To delete"
           OnClientClick="myclick(this.id);return false;"
        />

    <asp:Button ID="MyDelete" runat="server" Text="del" 
           CommandName="MyDelete"
           CommandArgument='<%# Eval("CartID") %>' 
           style="display:none"/>

  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

So, we WILL RETURN false and NOT have that image button server side click run, or do a post-back.

So, change the image button (to call our simple js function.

NOTE HOW we moved the features and information to our hidden "my delete" button.

As FYI:
Remember in a grid view, the commandName has SPECIAL meaning here. So, if we fill out both CommandName and CommandArgument, then the GridView “row command” event will fire!!!

And it looks like you doing that now anyway (using row command).

And here is the script + markup:

```
</asp:GridView>   ---- end of your gridview

<div id ="mydialog" style="display:none" runat="server">
     <h2>Do you really want to delete?</h2>
</div>

<script>
   function myclick(mycontrolid) {
      var mydiv = $('#mydialog');

      mydiv.dialog({
         autoOpen: false, modal: true, title: 'Delete?', width: '25%',
         position: { my: 'top', at: 'top+150' },
          buttons: {
             'ok': function () {
              vbtns = '#' + mycontrolid.replace('imgbtnDelete', 'MyDelete');
              $(vbtns).click();
              },
              'cancel': function () {
                        mydiv.dialog('close');
               }
          }
       });
       mydiv.dialog('open');
    }

</script>
```

And that is ALL you need here (remove that other "initialize" js junk you have).

The result should look like this:

[image]

So above is about the least amount of code for this to work. There are a dozen different ways to do this. But above is I think quite simple.

So, I have suggested the above since we in js do a “click()” of our delete button, and thus your existing code stub in the on-command row event can remain in place as you no doubt have it now. (So the suggested solution here takes into account your existing setup).

And for final good measure? our delete command will look like this:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCommand

    If e.CommandName = "MyDelete" Then

        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("DELETE FROM tblHotels where ID = " & e.CommandArgument,
                    New SqlConnection(My.Settings.Test3))
            cmdSQL.Connection.Open()
            cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using

        LoadGrid()    ' re-load the grid
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that you probably did call your code to load the grid up on first post (and NOT additonal post backs, but as above shows, WHEN you delete, you need to re-load the grid, since it does have a view state, and without a re-load of the grid view, then that deleted row WILL remain in view.

Edit: ----------------

It looks like the posted code DOES NOT include jQuery.UI.

You need BOTH jQuery, and ALSO need jQuery.UI. They are two separate libriies.

Also, jQuery.UI ALSO needs a style sheet, and it MUST be placed before the jQuery.UI referance.

The screen shots and working test code, starting at the "body" tag in the asp.net web form page looks like this:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" SortExpression="LastName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" SortExpression="FirstName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" SortExpression="HotelName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" SortExpression="City" />
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" 
                            OnClientClick="myclick(this.id);return false;"
                           />

                        <asp:Button ID="MyDelete" runat="server" Text="Button3" 
                            CommandName="MyDelete"
                            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' 
                            style="display:none"/>

                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

        <div id ="mydialog" style="display:none" runat="server">
            <h2>Do you really want to delete?</h2>
        </div>

    <script>

        function myclick(mycontrolid) {

            var mydiv = $('#mydialog');

            mydiv.dialog({
                autoOpen: false, modal: true, title: 'Delete?', width: '25%',
                position: { my: 'top', at: 'top+150' },
                buttons: {
                    'ok': function () {
                        vbtns = '#' + mycontrolid.replace('Button2', 'MyDelete');
                        $(vbtns).click();
                    },
                    'cancel': function () {
                        mydiv.dialog('close');
                    }
                }
            });
            mydiv.dialog('open');
        }

    </script>
</form>
</body>
```

Note I did place the jQuery and the jQuery.UI script references right inside of the form tag, but often users will place the references inside of the "head" tag.

but for ease of posting - I have included the jQuery, ad jQuery.UI references inside of the "form" tags.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Let me try this and I will get back to you. Give me  few hours

Comment: I tried to implement your code and nothing is happening when I am clicking on del button or click to delete. I made the changes to my post and also posted the image of what I am seeing.

Comment: As a test, then outside of the grid, simple place a plane jane asp.net buttion, and pop up a test dialog. In fact create a blank web page - drop a button, add the div and test + try the jQuery.UI dialog. I would HAVE to assume you run some test code and have jQuery.UI working. ONLY after you have  a simple test page with a simple button and jQuery.UI dialog working, then try the same on that page with the grid. As noted, MOST if not all web code does not block or wait. So you can't pop a jQuery.UI dialog and get a return value. You have to pop the dialog and THEN run code based on user choice

Comment: Just looking at what you have? You need to include BOTH jQuery, and jQuery.ui. You missing jQuery.ui in your script references. And it not clear why you using the mobile versions. I would start out with a clean test web page - simple button, simple "div", and a simple script that pops that dialog. Get that working before you go all hog wild on a complex page with grids and all kinds of stuff. And I would dump the mobile stuff until you first get a clean simple page up and running.  So, just looking at what you have, your missing the jQuery.UI reference. I'll post the full mark-up I have here.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Everything is working fine except postback does not occur when I delete the row. I posted my updated code along with the image in the original post.

Comment: If you want to place your row delete code stub to delete the row in the "row deleting" command? Then you have to change the command name = Delete. Note VERY carefull that CommandName has SPEICAL meaning here. If you  use "select", or "delete", then these commands are NOT made up names like I did with "MyDelete". If you change MyDelete (commandName) to Delete, then the row delete event stub WILL fire, and thus you can place/write/put/have your code to delete the row in that event code stub. I just placed the delete code in the row command - and then pick up "MyDelete".

Comment: Thank You!! I appreciate all your help. Code is working. I did notice MyDelete, but did not put it in my code behind.

Comment: So you can either: change CommandName="Delete" to cause the RowDeleting event to fire (and place your delete code in that event), or you can use RowCommand as I have and pick up a custom command say called CommandName="MySillyZooDelete", and pick up MySillyZooDelete command name in row command. So row command will fire in both cases. But if you do want to use rowDeleting event (and I suppose you should), then you have to change CommandName=Delete. So you can use RowDeleting if you want, but the command name thus has to be "Delete" for it to fire. Your choice to use either event stub.